# Bcrypt hashed password on client does not match that of the server password

Tags: android, spring-boot, kotlin, hash, bcrypt

So I have two projects that are supposed to communicate with each other. One being Android and the other Spring Boot. They both should be using Bcrypt as the hash encoder.

In my Android project (the client), the user registers their details. The main ones being username and password.

I understand that at this point, the client should be hashing the password and also salt? Then it needs to transmit the data securely to the server.

From there, the server then needs to process the information and store the hashed password and the salt.

The next time the user wishes to log into the app, they again, provide the username and their password, which again, the client hashes and then transmits to the server.

At this point, the server is supposed to compare the hashed password to the one stored on the database and all going well, they match.

This is where the problems lie.

In my client project, I register the user and send the hashed password over to the server with the following code:

```
...
        password = passwordEncoder().encode(password)

        apiService.addCustomer(
            ApiCustomer(
                username = username,
                password = password,
                dob = LocalDate.parse(convertDOB(dob)).toString(),
                firstName = firstName,
                lastName = lastName,
                isActive = true,
                email = email,
                mobileNumber = mobileNumber,
            )
        )
...
```

`passwordEncoder()` is initialised by the following:

```
fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder = BCryptPasswordEncoder()
```

With a password of say `password1`, this creates a has of `$2a$10$FgIbXCXzYrpwcKV8bS2BoulXDDBvwywXKB5MMyiUkQzDk66zTFli6`

So far so good. My server then receives this from the client and then stores the hashed password (not sure how I would implement salt yet). Again, so far so good. It does just that.

Now the user comes along later on and needs to log back in. So they provide their username and type in their raw password - same details as above.

My client then rehashes the password... `password1` becomes `$2a$10$J33C5WCT0zRh/P17R6soMupgQmkIh6JD9bPKPi4kUJhjGWnv0R6OW`

Even from a quick glance you can see that this does not match!

I'm guessing that this is to do with the salt I mentioned earlier. However, I'm not sure how I would extract the salt on the client side, then on the server side, use it to compare the newly hashed password.

Answer (score 3):

first of all it's normal behavior that bcrypt generates different hash every time because it adds a random generated value to the plain text password before it hashes it ( to protect against [rainbow table attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) )

so you give it password of **123** it adds random salt "**123+salt**(16-byte)" then hashes the whole text to something like this

```
$2a$12$R9h/cIPz0gi.URNNX3kh2OPST9/PgBkqquzi.Ss7KIUgO2t0jWMUW
\__/\/ \____________________/\_____________________________/
Alg Cost      Salt                        Hash
```

****notice the salt is contained within the hashed version**

this is saved to your DB, then generating the hash again will use **different random salt** and the whole (**123+diffSalt**) will be different input hence different hash.

the right way to compare plain password with hash is fetching the hash from DB use the salt on it to hash the plaintext password then compare them.

you can do it in springboot using

**`encoder.matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword)`**

> I'm not sure how I would extract the salt on the client side

you shouldn't be doing this in the client side (you would have to send the hashed password to the client to get the salt and compare which is not right) all hashing and comparing should be done in server side.

the recommended approach is to send the user's password in plain text over a secure connection (e.g. HTTPS) to the server, where it can be hashed using bcrypt and stored securely.
then when the user logins send the credentials again in plain text using HTTPS and now the server fetches the hash, compares the login password with the hashed one using the same salt on the hashed.